# How do I get the parent of hasClass()?

Tags: jquery

I just need to get the class of a parent of a class I found with `hasClass()` but it is not working.

```js
if ($('.test div').hasClass('has-error')) {
  console.log($(this).parent().className)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div class='test2'>
    <div class='has-error'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `$('.test div.has-error')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `this` will refer to the `window` as you're not in the scope of an element.

`hasClass` is also a little redundant here as you can just select the element with the given class directly and then perform your logic.

Finally, note that `className` is not a valid property of a jQuery object. Presumably `attr('class')` is what you require. Try this:

```js
var className = $('.test div.has-error').parent().attr('class');
console.log(className)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test2">
    <div class="has-error"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation this makes everything clear.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".test div").each(function() {
  
  if ($(this).hasClass('has-error')) {
    console.log($(this).hasClass('has-error'))
    console.log($(this).parent().attr("class"))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div class='test2'>
    <div class='has-error'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use like this

Comment: then hasClass would have no use because all of those div have that class maybe he has some reason why he needs to use hasClass

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to return element with `has-class` and then get class of its parent.

```js
var c = $('.test div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).hasClass('has-error')
}).parent().attr('class')

console.log(c)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div class='test2'>
    <div class='has-error'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe for some reason op wants to do this with `hasClass`